# Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone

I got the following error when I am Building Solution for my app.

> Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Windows phone 7.1 Silverligt Application.
64-bit operating system.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've got a problem with your hard drive.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com, reinstall Silverlight.

Comment: @jimmy Please don't cross-post your questions across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly, you are trying to load a DLL that is specifically for Windows 7/xp 64 bit into the phone7 OS. then you get this errormessage.